# Duplicate packets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Is there a simple way to do a 1:1 copy of a TCP packet in Java and send it back, so as to force the client's TCP implementation to automatically discard it? Or am I approaching this the wrong way? It seems like a simple thing to do but has me stumped.

**EDIT** Would a raw sockets library be of any relevance here, or is it not strictly required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy and resend all the payload data you want.

No, there's no way to recreate the TCP/IP headers (and/or Ethernet frame headers) directly with Java sockets.

You might wish to look at libpcap:

http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply... so a raw sockets library is required to perform this sort of thing? I have heard of RockSaw, never used it but apparently it allows you to do whatever you like...

Answer (score 1):

TCP packet duplication should be done in the kernel level, since the TCP/IP headers are filled in kernel level.

Maybe you need to recompile the linux kernel, and modify the TCP/IP stack implementation, to simulate packet drop and duplication.